# Migrating from Axis to Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, axis

I need help migrating an Axis project to Axis2.

I'm working on an older Axis project, and some of the Java classes were generated from WSDL using the older WSDL2Java tool. 
The problem now is, Java sees that as an error, since I have the latest Axis2 version 1.6.

I've been told to regenerate the Java classes from the the WSDL file using the WSDL2Java tool found in Axis2, however, the classes 
generated are completely different to the older WSDL2Java.

How would I rework my way around this? I don't feel the project would work if I replace the older classes with the newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axis 2 was a ***significant*** rewrite of the framework. There is no real shortcut around the upgrade, you will need to deal with it or remain on Axis 1 (as some people actually decided to do).  The [official migration guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/migration.html) provides some helpful tips, though it does not detail everything you will need to know in order to successfully complete the migration.

Since you will be going through the pains of an upgrade, I would be remiss if I didn't suggest you take a look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). It is a more modern web service framework, with support for JAX-WS ***and*** JAX-RS. And if you do contract first development then your clients will not have to be upgraded (just the server implementation side).

Comment: Ah, thanks! Using Eclipse, I created the Web Service using Axis instead of Axis2 and it worked brilliantly.

Comment: Yep, but it has vulnerabilities as CVE-2019-0227